# Python: copy folder content recursively

Tags: python, file, recursion, copy

I want to copy the content of a folder recursively without copying files that already exist. Also, the destination Folder already exists and contains files.
I tried to use [shutils.copytree(source_folder, destination_folder)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree), but it does not do what I want.

I want it to work like this:

**Before:**

- source_folder

  - sub_folder_1

    - foo
    - bar
  - sub_folder_2

---

- destination_folder

  - folder_that_was_already_there

    - file2.jpeg
  - some_file.txt
  - sub_folder_1

    - foo

**After:**

- destination_folder

  - folder_that_was_already_there

    - file2.jpeg
  - some_file.txt
  - sub_folder_1

    - foo
    - bar
  - sub_folder_2

Comment: Could you clarify, what was not working? It seems you have some specific logic related to what file to copy and what not, do not expect shutils to do it for you, this has to be decided in your code. Could you show us some code?

Comment: Use os.walk() to enumerate the source tree, os.path.exists() to see if the destination exists, os.stat() to see if the destination is older and os.mkdir()/shutil.copy2() to do the deed.

Comment: tdelaney was right. I implementet it. Will post it as an answer as soon as i'm allowed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney):
source_folder is the path to the source and destination_folder the path to the destination.

```
import os
import shutil

def copyrecursively(source_folder, destination_folder):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for item in files:
        src_path = os.path.join(root, item)
        dst_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, src_path.replace(source_folder, ""))
        if os.path.exists(dst_path):
            if os.stat(src_path).st_mtime > os.stat(dst_path).st_mtime:
                shutil.copy2(src_path, dst_path)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(src_path, dst_path)
    for item in dirs:
        src_path = os.path.join(root, item)
        dst_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, src_path.replace(source_folder, ""))
        if not os.path.exists(dst_path):
            os.mkdir(dst_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree)? The `update` parameter is defaulted to `0` but it seems like you'd want `1`, which would only copy if files don't exist at the destination or are older. I don't see any requirement in your question that `copy_tree()` won't cover.